# Django: NoReverseMatch at / 'myapp' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have this error during template rendering. What i'm trying to do is allow the user to upload a csv then process the data into models.

error at line 109
'myapp' is not a registered namespace

This is my line 109 code

```
<form action="{% url "myapp:upload_csv" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

urls.py in mysite

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('anomaly.urls')),
]
```

urls.py in anomaly

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^upload/csv/$', views.upload_csv, name='upload_csv'),
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this
urls.py in mysite

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('anomaly.urls',namespace='anomaly'))
```

To qualify a url name with a namespace use the syntax 'namespace:name'

```
<form action="{% url 'anomaly:upload_csv' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

Comment: i have try your sugguestions, however, when i tried to run it shows me 
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

in cmd, it shows me this message

 'Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name '
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name is not supported. Set the app_name attribute in the included module, or pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name instead.

Comment: in addition, in my settings.py i have already added 'anomaly' to my installed apps

Comment: I have solved the issue already by adding app_name="anomaly" in urls.py in my anomaly app

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you have switched to Django 2.0 This is one of the change the new version of Django contains.
Go to urls.py of your app anomaly and add the `app_name = "anomaly"`. So your urls.py file will be like

```
    app_name = "anomaly"

    urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    url(r'^upload/csv/$', views.upload_csv, name='upload_csv'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your app name is `anomaly`. You should write this like this

```
<form action="{% url "anomaly:upload_csv" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this quite a few times when upgrading sites to the latest version of Django.

Creating a new app will create a file called `apps.py` which would look something like this:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

    class MyappConfig(AppConfig):
        name = 'myapp'
```

I would usually add this file to all apps in a project that is being updated. Replace with the name of the app, then add this `app_name = MyappConfig.name` to the `urls.py` for the app.

You can find out more information about Configuring Application [here in the Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)