# can I display (django's detailview) on (Bootstrap's Modal view)?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-bootstrap4

I wanna Open an **object details**(DetailView) in a **Bootstrap Modal dialog**(not redirecting to another page) as in the pic below:

[I found this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53252429/12150875)
a little complicated cos I'm not used to Ajax

thnx in advance

Comment: Yes you can, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I would recommend you to look at this https://dmorgan.info/posts/django-views-bootstrap-modals/. In the worst case, you should consider learning `ajax`, it is not that hard to be honest.